# How to render a Partial view that supports pagination in a neat way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I ma trying to render a partial view **that supports pagination**. I want to look pretty on my Index page. For this, it must inherits the master page. If I do so it will appear twice the footer. I could make another master page  without footer, and DRY principle is obviously broken. Not to mention that it is only for one page.

I tried putting as PartialViewResult, but I am still not getting the expected result. It prompts an error, since I am using pagination.

Here is my code if it helps:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {

                int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberOfUserTasksPerPage"]); ;
                int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
                return View(_userTasksTasks.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And the view:
[image]

As I said, an idea would be to make another master page similar to the default one, but it will have no footer. That will be the only difference. I want to do it neater.

Any ideas?

Much appreciated your suggestions,
Liviu

Comment: Why does it need to inherit the master page? If it's sitting as a partial in the master layout, it will already be seeing styles and scripts from master.... Have you tried it without inheriting the master page?

Comment: I think you are confused... using pagination does not mean you HAVE to use a layout page, neither does it mean that you cannot use a partial view. You cannot use Javascript in partial views - which may be your issue if your pagination uses JS. Try the Partial view approach, however put the Javascript in the master page instead. This will work as we have implemented many apps this way. If you don't use JS in your pagination, try posting your whole page and we can help as this is certainly doable in a normal way you must be missing something....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the bottom. Use JQuery or any library that you are comfortable with. It is the only work arround that I can come up with

Comment: This is not a good solution, it is a hack and leads to very confusing code. I would not let that through a code review...